# question about multivariable limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Do we use the resource of approaching  a limit from different paths, such as $y = x$, $y = kx$, $ y=x^2$ and so on only to prove that the limit is different and then claim that it doesn't exist or we can also use it to prove that it actually exists?

I'm under the impression that if we wish to prove that the limit exists we transform the limit until we get a constant value or use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

I'm wondering whether approaching a limit from different paths can also be used to prove there exists a limit.

Comment: Nope. Calculating the limits of a finite different restrictions can't be used to prove the limit exists. And doing that for an infinite number of restrictions isn't feasible so...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no as the limit has to be the same for every single path of which there are infinitely many (essentially relating to the infinite directions from which you can approach the point).

Answer (score 0):

Approaching a point using different paths and finding different limits is an effective and efficient way to prove that the limit **doesn't exist**. Unfortunately, proving that several pathways result in the same limit isn't sufficient to prove the existence of the limit (since there are uncountably infinite possible pathways). To prove existence, we must use an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof or some other clever trick (such as the Squeeze Theorem or converting to polar coordinates).